# How Do I Style ReactMarkdown Code Blocks?

Tags: reactjs, markdown, react-markdown

I'm working on a React project and I'm trying to format the code blocks in my markdown content using ReactMarkdown. I've encountered an issue where my code blocks are unformatted and bland. I attempted to use remarkPlugins for syntax highlighting, but to no avail.

### Code:

```
<ReactMarkdown>{blog.markdownBody}</ReactMarkdown>
```

What can I do to ensure this code is beautiful presented, like for example vscode?